# Python String Iteration/Functions

Tags: python, function

I need my 'items' variable to print each item on a new line. I keep getting a total in 'items' and the total in 'total'.  The 'total' prints out how I want, but I want the items to print individually.

Thoughts?

```
def adding_report():
    user_input = input("Report Types include All Items ('A') or Total Only ('T')\nChoose Report Type ('A'or'T'):") 
    items = "\n"
    total = 0
    while True:
        if user_input == 'A'.lower():
            user_input1 = input("Input an integer to add to the total or 'Q' to quit: ")
            if user_input1.isdigit():
                items = int(user_input1)
                total += int(user_input1)
                continue
            elif user_input1 == 'Q'.lower():
                print("Items\n", items)
                print("Total\n", total)
                break
            elif user_input1.startswith('q'):
                print('Items\n', int(items))
                print("Total\n", total)
                break
            else:
                print("Input is not valid")
        elif user_input == 'T'.lower():
            user_input2 = input("Input an integer to add the total or 'Q' to quit: ")

adding_report()
```

Comment: `'Q'.lower()` ?? why not `q`?

Comment: Could you edit with an example of output you precisely want?

Comment: If the first `user_input` is anything besides `a` and `t`, your code will immediately enter an infinite loop.

Comment: Try `items += user_input1`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I have tried that and the 'items' concatenate instead of printing on a new line every time.  I also realized I'm missing half the code. all apologies. See below:

Comment: if user_input2.isdigit():
                items += user_input2
                total += int(user_input2)
                continue
            elif user_input2== 'Q'.lower():
                print("Total\n", total)
                break
            elif user_input2.startswith('q'):
                print("Total\n", total)
            else:
                print("Input is not invalid")
        else:
            print("Input is invalid")
            continue

adding_report()

Comment: Would like for it to show:
Items
3
4
4
Total
11
(But all print on new lines)

Comment: If your solution is worth sharing, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = raw_input("Report Types include All Items ('A') or Total Only ('T')\nChoose Report Type ('A'or'T'):")
items=[]
total = 0
print user_input
total = 0
while True:
    user_input1 = raw_input("Input an integer to add to the total or 'Q' to quit: ")
    if user_input == 'A'.lower() or user_input == "A":
        if user_input1.isdigit():
            items.append(int(user_input1))
            total += int(user_input1)
            continue
        elif user_input1 == 'Q'.lower() or user_input1 =="Q" or user_input1.startswith('q'):
            print "List of items is"
            for item in items:
                print item
            print "Total ", total
            break
        else:
            print("Input is not valid")
    elif user_input == 'T'.lower() or user_input == "T":
        if user_input1.isdigit():
            items.append(int(user_input1))
            total += int(user_input1)
            continue
        elif user_input1 == 'Q'.lower() or user_input1 =="Q" or user_input1.startswith('q'):
            print "Total ",total
            break
        else:
            print("Input is not valid")
```

Comment: Use parentheses with `print` so it works with both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: You should maybe add some comments or explanation, just dumping modified code for copy&paste isn't really helping the OP in the long run, they need to understand mistakes and how they were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified code. It is hard to exactly understand what your script is supposed to do:

```
import textwrap # nice library to format text inside functions

def adding_report():

    # initiate variables
    total = 0
    items = 0

    # Make sure you get the right input
    while True:
        user_input = input(textwrap.dedent("""\
            Report Types include All Items ('A') or Total Only ('T')
            Choose Report Type ('A'or'T'):""")) 
        if user_input list("AT"):
            break

    # Create a loop where you ask the user for input
    # Q or q quits (the print is outside the function)
    while True:
        user_input1 = input("Input an integer to add to the total or 'Q' to quit: ")
        if user_input1.lower() == 'q':
            break
        if user_input1.isdigit():              
            if user_input == 'A':
                items = int(user_input1)
                total += int(user_input1)
            elif user_input == 'T':
                total += int(user_input1)
        else:
            print("Input is not valid")

    # Return variables   
    return items,total


items,total = adding_report()
print("Items\n", items)
print("Total\n", total)
```

Comment: Thank you for all your input.  The above code looks very similar to what I got.   When 'Q' is finally selected out of 'A', I need the inputted 'items' (integers) to print individually on new lines.   
When 'T' is selected, the total prints only.  When 'A' is selected, then the Items print individually (on new lines) then the Total (of the items/integers) prints also

Comment: The above is very close.   The 'items' are still not printing verticall (one of top of each other).  They are printing side by side.  This is beyond frustrating.....
Also, the items variable is an empty string.  The total variable is a counter

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at understanding what you trying to do:

```
print("Report Types includes All Items ('A') or Total Only ('T')")
report_type_raw = input("Choose Report Type ('A' or 'T'): ")

report_type = report_type_raw.lower()

if report_type in 'at':
    items = []
    total = 0

    user_input = ''

    while user_input != 'q':
        user_input_raw = input("Input an integer to add to the total or 'Q' to quit: ")
        if user_input_raw.isdigit():
            current_item = int(user_input_raw)

            if report_type == 'a':
                items.append(user_input_raw)

            total += current_item
            user_input = ''
        else:
            user_input = user_input_raw.lower()
            if user_input != 'q':
                print("Input is not valid")

    if report_type == 'a':
        how_items_to_be_printed = ', '.join(items)
        print("Items :", how_items_to_be_printed)

    print("Total :", total)
else:
    print("Report type is not valid")
```

Otherwise you'll have to clarify what you were trying to do.

Comment: No list [] required.   Just when 'items' printed, each item is to be printed on a new line

Comment: If you want each item on a new line change line `how_items_to_be_printed = ', '.join(items)` to `how_items_to_be_printed = '\n'.join(items)` and line `print("Items :", how_items_to_be_printed)` to line `print("Items :\n" + how_items_to_be_printed)`

Comment: If you think my answer is appropriate can you consider accepting the answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers